# GLUT_ICON not working on top left window

Tags: c++, freeglut

am trying to add an icon application that uses freeglut, according to the doc [here](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php) it seems is enough to have an icon resource GLUT_ICON. 
Although it worked, it only appears on the icon of the console window and the executable in windows explorer, but the main window remains with the default windows icon (as shown in the image). I tried building without the console window mode, but I get same behavior, is this the way it suppose to work or am getting a wrong behavior?
[image: Main window without icon]

Answer (score 2):

This might help clear things for others running into the same problem:

https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/151647-opengl-glut-icon/

Basically, in the "file.rc"resource-file  (right click view code) that appears after adding an ico resouce, where you should have

```
MAINICON ICON "compiler_assets\\icon-name.ico" //set main icon to "file"
```

You should add another line

```
GLUT_ICON ICON DISCARDABLE "compiler_assets\\icon-name.ico"
```

Which is basically setting `GLUT_ICON` to a specific .ico file

Comment: right click -> view code was the savior. Thank you mucho. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this problem. Whether this issues come from the VStudio2012 environment or not is uncertain.
But generating the resource id like this; GLUT_ICON creates a non-defined behavior. The exe is unable to identify this tag as a valid one, therefore no icon can be indexed and found.
By just changing to lower case the string, all problems get fixed.
I did this process manually and the fix seems to be consistent between PC's.